# Next.js - 404 error without .html extension when deploying static output

Tags: html, next.js, webserver, static-pages

My website uses Next.js and is deployed with static output using FileZilla.

I can reach the root of my website without a `.html` extension, like seen below:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com
```

When I try to reach any other page on the server I get a 404 error unless I provide the `.html` extension.

Doesn't work: `https://www.mywebsite.com/en/marine/modelvirtue`
Works: `https://www.mywebsite.com/en/marine/modelvirtue.html`

This does not happen when I run my project in development mode using VSCode.